# Windows SQL Server 2016 Express - permissions don't work

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I try to give a user on SQL Server 2016 Express the permission to create tables in his schema, but he can do what he wants. And I don't know why he is unable to do this.

This is the server role:

[image]

And this is the Schema role:

[image]

This is the database role:
(I only checked "CREATE TABLE")

[image]

And this is the user:

[image]

So why can the user do INSERT, DELET, UPDATE - Statments and so on? From where did he get the permission?

I hope someone can help me?

Comment: Is it possible that the public role is able to do UPDATE, DELETE and SELECT Statments?

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a3a424e-bb6e-4168-a3be-b192947e9e95/create-new-schema-and-grant-user-full-control-to-schema?forum=sqlsecurity) which looks like it addresses what you're trying to do.

Comment: @K_foxer9 thx But how can I make a schema what does Not own from dbo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the anwser is that a owner of Schema have all permissions to this Schema so he can do INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE Statments and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a schema, you can grant `CONTROL` permissions to the user:
`grant control on schema :: testschema to TestUser`

You can change ownership of the schema with 
`alter authorization on schema::testsch to TestUser`

Be aware that you can't limit `CREATE TABLE` permissions to just a schema, so it has to be granted at the database level, but if you don't give the user permissions in the other schemas, they can't create tables in them.

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a3a424e-bb6e-4168-a3be-b192947e9e95/create-new-schema-and-grant-user-full-control-to-schema?forum=sqlsecurity), particularly Rick Byham's answer, is the source of most of this.

Comment: thx again for the anwser. But this is not my problem. The problem is when i add a user to the schema he can do INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Statments and so on. And i dont know why. Because The user doesn´t have the permission, the schema doesn´t have the permission. So from where did he get the permission to do this statments?